# Чтение и запись обратно в csv с DictReader и OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dict

Прочитал csv файл и надо удалить конкретное поле и записать csv обратно.
Как обратиться к конкретному полю словаря и записать его?

```
csvfile = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=';')
for line in csvfile:
    if line["Image"]:
        print ('есть текст в поле - очистить')
        # удалить поле line["Image"], как сделать? 

# записать новый csv файл из dict файла
writecsv(csvfile)
```

Answer (score -1):

решил задачу, если кому поможет, открытие csv и запись в голом виде, если нужна обработки полей записи то в for по line через if:

```
newline = []
    import csv
    with open("../CSV_main.csv", encoding='utf-8') as f_obj:
        csv = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=';')
        for line in csv:              
                newline.append(line)
    #запись csv обратно
    fieldnames = [t for i, t in enumerate(newline[0])]
    with open('../CSV_main_UPD.csv', "w", newline='') as out_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, delimiter=';', fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in newline:
            writer.writerow(row)
```